# how to include dll library with makefile, when using rcpp/rinside package

Tags: c++, r, dll, rcpp, rinside

I am using R with Rinside/Rcpp package. I was able to generate .exe/.o/.dll files (A) from come C++ code I wrote based on Rinside package.

However, later I found I would like to use A.dll as library for my other function. But I cannot figure out a way to do that. Any hints? Or any doc out there that I can refer to?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

RInside comes with four directories filled with examples, and three of those use, respectively

- MPI for parallel computing
- Qt for GUI apps
- Wt for Web apps

and each has a working  Makefile showing you exactly how to set up linking with an external library, besides the R, Rcpp and RInside libraries already used.